# Selecting text from shell in neovim

Tags: neovim, shell

I like to execute my scripts in the shell using

```
:! %
```

But once I do, I can't select the text from the shell in the output. I'm currently using neovim.
When I click into the shell to select the text, I exit the shell. How can I get around this?

Comment: Not sure what the clicking issue is about, but consider using `:terminal %` instead

Comment: May be use `r! %` to load the op in buffer, do what you want with it and then press `u` to undo

Comment: Does balki's suggestion work for you @pepperdreamteam ?

Comment: @gildux not quite

Answer (score 0):

The `%` in `! %` is a shortcut for the name of your current file, not the contents of the file.

If I name a file ls and open it in vim and run `! %` the output of the ls command will be shown.

Comment: with all due respect, this information is completely unrelated to the question. there is nothing wrong with the question

Comment: I was just clarifying how you used the `! %`. 

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. You can pipe the output of the command through xclip to copy it, and then simply paste it into a new vim buffer.

2. Another solution is to pipe the output of the command to vim with `[command] | vim -` to do some work there before copying/saving the output och parts of the output.

3. `:%![command]` to run the current file through the command and view the output in current buffer.

Comment: These suggestions only work for stdout. Terminal mode seems to be the only way so far

Comment: It works for gVim and Vim, Terminal *and* stand-alone version.

Comment: Yes, not for neovim. This was a Neovim question

Answer (score 0):

Usually for this kind of stuff I use the vim function `read`

```
:read! ls
```

or

```
:read! date
```

It will print the output/results inside the current buffer

If the shell interaction needs a but more interaction, I do things in the shell, pipe to files, and use command line tool `xclip` for moving around the intersting stuffs from places to places as well inside as oustide vim